# Can I identify string [] inner value?

Tags: c#

I have a task and I have to check how many odd numbers there are. For example:

```
cw(string[54]); //37 42 44 61 62
```

From this I need to get how many odd numbers are in this string. The only way I figured out was to cut the string into 5 ints so int 1 is 37, 2 is 42 and so on. But that is a really long and slow process even with methods.

Any help, or shall I stick with the "cutting" which looks something like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < all_number.Length; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {            
        cutter = all_number[y];
        placeholder = cutter.IndexOf(" ");
        final[x] = Convert.ToInt32(cutter.Remove(placeholder));
    }
}
```

This one is for the first numbers, so at 37 42 44 61 62 final would be 37.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, `all_number` is the string which contains all your numbers, and you want to get only the odd numbers in the string?

Comment: You should really look into `String.Split`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start by using an outer `foreach` loop rather than referring array values by index, unless the index is important (which it doesn't look like it is here).

I'd then use `string.Split` to split each string by spaces, and then LINQ to sum the odd numbers.

For example:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var oddSum = line.Split(' ')
        .Select(int.Parse)                   // Parse each chunk
        .Where(number => (number & 1) == 1)  // Filter out even values
        .Sum();                              // Sum all the odd values
    // Do whatever you want with the sum of the odd values for this line
}
```

If you actually only want to *count* the odd numbers, you can use the overload of `Count` that accepts a predicate:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var oddCount = line.Split(' ')
        .Select(int.Parse)                   // Parse each chunk
        .Count(number => (number & 1) == 1)  // Count the odd values
    // Do whatever you want with the count of the odd values for this line
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception (in `int.Parse`) at the first non-integer value encountered. That may well be fine, but you can use `int.TryParse` to avoid the exception. That's harder to use with LINQ though; please specify how you want them handled if you need this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use the built in tools you have available.

To split a string by a predefined character, use `Split`:

```
var numbers = allNumbersString.Split(' ');
```

Now you have an array of strings, each holding a string representation of what we hope is a number.

Now we need to extract numbers out of each string. The safest way to do this is using `int.TryParse`:

```
foreach (var n in numbers)
{
     if (int.TryParse(out var number)
     {
         //ok we got a number
     }
     else
     {
         //we don't. Do whatever is appropriate:
         //ignore invalid number, log parse failure, throw, etc.
     }
}
```

And now, simply return those that are odd: `number % 2 !=  0`;

Putting it all together:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ExtractOddNumbers(
    string s
    char separator)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name(s));

    foreach (var n in s.Split(separator))
    {
         if (int.TryParse(out var number)
         {
             if (number % 2 != 0)
                 yield return number;
         }
    }
}
```

So, if you want to know how many odd numbers there are in a given string, you would do:

```
var countOfOddNumbers = ExtractOddNumbers(s, ' ').Count();
```

The good thing about this approach is that now, its easily extensible. A small modification to our current method makes it a whole lot more powerful:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ExtractNumbers(
    string s
    char separator
    Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name(s));

    foreach (var n in s.Split(separator))
    {
         if (int.TryParse(out var number)
         {
             if (predicate(number))
                 yield return number;
         }
    }
}
```

See what we've done? We've made the filtering criteria one more argument of the method call; now you can extract numbers based on any condition. Odd numbers? `ExtractNumbers(s, ' ', n => n % 2 != 0)`. Multiples of 7? `ExtractNumbers(s, ' ', n => n % 7 == 0)`. Greater than 100? `ExtractNumbers(s, ' ', n => n > 100)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the `Split` method is what you're after.

if you want the count of odd numbers then you can accomplish the task like so:

```
var oddCount = lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(' ')) // flatten                         
                    .Select(int.Parse) // parse the strings
                    .Count(n => n % 2 != 0); // count the odd numbers
```

or if you want the summation you can do:

```
var oddSum = lines.SelectMany(line => line.Split(' '))// flatten                      
                  .Select(int.Parse) // parse the strings
                  .Where(n => n % 2 != 0)// retain the odd numbers
                  .Sum();// sum them
```

This assumes there will be no invalid characters in the string, otherwise, you'll need to perform checks with the `Where` clause prior to proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to loop over the string's characters and, if the current character is a space or the end of the string and the previous character is '1', '3', '5', '7' or '9' (odd numbers end with an odd figure), increase the count.

This allows the string to contain numbers that are much bigger than ints, does not allocate new memory (as with String.Split) and doesn't require the parsing of ints. It does assume a valid string with valid numbers:

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < cw.Length; i++)
{ 
    int numberIndex = -1;

    if(i == cw.Length - 1) numberIndex = i;
    if(cw[i] == ' ') numberIndex = i - 1;

    if(numberIndex != -1)
    {
        if(cw[numberIndex] == '1' || cw[numberIndex] == '3' || 
           cw[numberIndex] == '5' || cw[numberIndex] == '7' ||
           cw[numberIndex] == '9')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```